# Why does `call dword 0x12345678` compile to [66,E8,72,56,34,12]?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
$ cat call.s
call dword 0x12345678
$ nasm call.s
$ ndisasm call
00000000  66E872563412      call dword 0x12345678
```

Why is the result [66,E8,**72**,56,34,12] not [66,E8,**78**,56,34,12]? Why did `0x78` change into `0x72`?

Comment: Because this instruction is 6 bytes long.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Sorry, I'm new to asm... Is there no way to call an absolute address on the machine code level?

Comment: The call address is encoded as an offset applied to the EIP register.  After it has loaded the CALL instruction, its value won't be 0x00000000 but 0x000000006.  So it is 0x00000006 + 0x12345672 == 0x12345678

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **are** calling an absolute address with this instruction, although it may not seem so obvious at the first glance. Let's go through the assembly process step by step.

Firstly, you can see that your instruction has been assembled to `66 E8`. `66` is the operand size prefix - I'll explain why it got there later. `E8` points to the `CALL` instruction, which is expected, and the following bytes - `72563412` - are the little-endian representation of the 32-bit displacement relative to the instruction **after** the `CALL` instruction. This is actually how all relative jumps and calls are encoded in x86 : because the CPU always knows the current value of the instruction pointer, it can just add the value specified by the instruction to that value and execute a call/jump.

Secondly, there is a question **why** the assembler chose to assemble the instruction this way. If you are actually running `nasm` without any flags, then it defaults to the `bin` output mode, which just outputs raw opcodes into the file you specify. Additionally, it defaults to assembling instructions in 16-bit mode in that output mode. This is why the `66` prefix is there : it was possible to execute instructions with 32-bit operands in 16-bit mode, provided that this prefix was present in front of the opcode. Also, `nasm` in `bin` output mode assumes that the resulting binary begins at address `0` : this is why the "offset" of your call is `72563412` - if the IP starts at 0, then it will be 6 after processing the `CALL`, and `0x6 + 0x12345672` gives you `0x12345678`, which is the address you wanted to call. You can change the offset at which the program is loaded via the `ORG` (origin) directive.

If you don't want to use jumps/calls with relative addressing, then you will have to put the address of the code which you want to jump to/call in a register, and then execute the instruction with the register as an operand. Something like this :

```
mov eax, somecode
jmp eax

somecode:
    int 3
```

Assembles to the following :

```
00000000  66B809000000      mov eax,0x9
00000006  66FFE0            jmp eax
00000009  CD03              int 0x3
```

You can see that the absolute address of the jump is moved directly into the register. However, if you're simply executing jumps/calls to labels, I can't think of any reasons why you wouldn't use relative addressing. The CPU always knows its current IP - and your assembler should, too.

Comment: I want to use absolute addressing because I want to change the address on the fly. Thanks for your impressive answer!

Comment: In that case, indirect addressing via the register is what you're looking for. In case you want to read something more about practical usage of this, look up "jump tables".